# How to create this kind of shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, blur

Does anyone know how to create this kind of blur on a shape? I guess it's easiest in Photoshop[image].

Answer (score 2):

.. could be done with a **Gradient Mesh** in Illustrator....

[image]

.. or a blend in Illustrator....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop you could use *Filter > Blur Gallery > Field Blur*

Move the blur control and click to create a second blur control point. Then you can adjust the blurs separately.

An example

[image]